# Running a python program from a terminal issue

Tags: python, terminal

Basically this is something that I had an issue with running C programme and I'm trying to run a python program from a terminal but the problem arises again. after tying an exact file in a exact directory the terminal doesn't seem to run the program and just skip it.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong to run and display on a terminal 
command?

```
$ ls
hello_world.py
$ python hello_world.py
$
```

This below 'script' is how I run the code with sublime text. Basically from my point of view there is no problem in script itself..

```
print('Hello Python world!')
```

Comment: Could you show the code inside `hello_world.py`?

Comment: Did you look, if the process of this programm starts? And we need the code from hello_world.py

Comment: I just edited and added the code and script. Basically I'm using sublime test editor. Is there something problem in script editor?

Comment: Whenever this kind of thing happens to me I am not running the same file I am changing. You can check it's content before running with `cat` for example.

Comment: [Don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), copy-paste the actual code and command line output instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your python is properly installed then there is no problem with the terminal. Python interpreter executes code line by line.It is completing the file and coming out of it.

Comment: At least let us know what you are expecting as output

Comment: I saw your edit now. Have you saved your file before compiling it ?

Comment: Yes, I saved the file in a directory called 'python_work' in desktop and typed 'python hello_world.py' in terminal. Are there some setting required when using sublime text prior to downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have this kind of problem it is because the file I'm trying to run is not the same I am changing. I recommend using something (like `cat`) to check the content of the file before actually running it.

So, in your case, pop up your terminal and run:

```
$ cat hello_world.py
```

The output should be

```
$ cat hello_world.py
print("Hello Python World!")
```

If the output is blank, there is your problem. Try to open that exact file with `sublime`. Probably with

```
$ sublime hello_world.py
```

Answer (score -4):

At the top of your .py file

Add

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Then when you need to give your file permissions

```
chmod +x hello_world.py
```

Then to run

```
./hello_world.py
```

This will run it in python3 if you want python2 just change that in the usr/bin

Comment: That's not going to do a change to the problem and also you missed the part where you set execute permissions.

Comment: Actually it probably will